# kill a shell created by vim when ctrl-C doesn't work

Tags: python, shell, unix, vim

I'm writing some threaded python code in vim. When I run my tests, with

`:! py.test test_me.py`

Sometimes they hang and cannot be killed with ctrl-C. So I have to background vim (actually the shell the tests are running in) and `pkill py.test`. Is there a better way to kill the hanging test suite?

I tried mapping `:map ,k:! pkill py.test` but this doesn't work since while the tests are running my input is going to the shell running the test, not vim.

EDIT:
I'm looking for a way to kill the test process that is quicker than `ctrl-Z`, `pkill py.test`, `fg` `<cr>` to return to editing. Ideally just a hotkey.

Comment: Have you tried through PID?

Comment: I would like to be able to kill my hanging tests without having to background vim. 

I can `kill 1234` the tests if I background vim.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `:!` in Vim, you effectively put Vim into background and the running process, in this case `py.test`, gets the focus. That means you can't tell Vim to kill the process for you since Vim is not getting keystrokes from you.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> puts Vim into background while running `py.test` because Vim is the parent process of `py.test`. Thus the shell goes through the chain then puts all children as well as the parent into background.

I would suggest that you open another terminal window and do all the housekeeping chores there.